# How to swap the hexadecimal numbers in c language?

Tags: c, hex

How to swap the following two hexadecimal numbers in c language? Eg:

input :0xabcd
output:0xcdab

Comment: ...which was edited away from the question that was already answered.

Comment: also: no signature necessary in your posts.

Comment: I reverted the other question; it should be deleted if OP doesn't want it there anymore, since there's an answer there. Unfortunately, I'd already voted to close as a dup before noting this.

Comment: _How_ exactly is that possible duplicate a duplicate? It's _nothing_ like this question!

Comment: @paxdiablo: @venkat editted the marked as referenced question to be exactly same as this one,so at the time of closure, it was an exact dupe. @Wooble reverted it only afterward.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use something along the lines of:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main (void) {
    unsigned int from = 0xabcd;
    unsigned int to = ((from & 0xff) << 8) | (from >> 8);
    printf ("%04x\n", to);
    return 0;
}
```

This swaps the two bytes around, giving you an output of `cdab`.

Answer (score 0):

What platform? Windows offers `_byte_swap` with various sizes. Else you could just bit shift it.

Answer (score -2):

One of my professors showed me this bit fiddling technique for swapping integers that I've always found elegant:

```
int x = 5;
int y = 7;
x = x ^ y;
y = x ^ y;
x = x ^ y; // x = 7, y = 5
```

Comment: I'm cool with being down-voted, but I'd like to know why at least.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but if you look at the example in the question, it's actually asking how to swap the byte order rather than how to swap two variables. Also, while the xor trick is clever, it's usually slower and more error-prone than using a temporary variable.

Comment: I'll blame it on a poorly worded question. :) Thanks for the feedback @interjay